# How to avoid using the same account from multiple machines?

Tags: asp.net, session-state, application-pool

**Requirement**:
A user can login only once per session period.  for example,  if a user login to the website from two different machines the website will show a message "The account is already in use".  That would apply if the user login from two different browsers.

I am working on a web application that uses "InProc" Session. the app do the following:

```
A- When user login, Put Session_ID, user_ID and IP in a table called Sessions.

B- When Session_End is called, Set the row of Sessions table to be marked InActive.

C- When Application_Start is called, the web app deactivate all Sessions.
```

First: I don't like this, it causes a deadlock in the database. I can't verify the reason yet.

Second: Is session_end gurantee to run in all cases, I could not find MSDN page says that Session_End is called when App pool is recycled.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end.aspx

Do you have a better idea? Does Session_End is called **everytime** App pool is recycled?

Thanks

Comment: Viewed 20 times and no answers, Is it too complicated? or too difficult to understand question?!

Comment: Note: when the user closes his browser, he will not be able to log in again until the previous session expires. Make sure to tell that to the stakeholders, before they log it as a "bug".

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have is conceptually correct, however I don't think you can rely on the session_end event firing, as this will only happen if the user hits your site when their session has expired, rather than just closing the browser.

What you also probably need is a service that runs on a fairly regular basis and removes items from your session table after a certain period has passed (you may want a date field that is updated when a session is created/refreshed).

Don't know where you deadlock is coming from, but am guessing that you're not closing something properly...

Comment: "as this will only happen if the user hits your site when their session has expired".  
that is not accurate, Session_End is called through HttpApplication instance when the session is abodon or expire regardless of any HTTP hits.

Comment: Maybe so, but the comment from Hans Kesting on the question does very much apply here.